# Electret Mic signal amplification without DC offset

Tags: amplifier, electret

I'm working on a small audio project and I need a circuit that does the following: take a signal from an electret mic, **rectify** the signal, **amplify** it, and **remove the DC offset**. I have tried many circuit designs but they are not working fine with me (too much noise and with DC offset). Should I mention that the electret mic's resistant is approximately 2.8 kΩ. Thanks in advance. any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you should share with us the "many circuit designs" you have tried - this would save folk wasting their time on lost causes that you would inevitably reject. Alternatively, sit back, pay attention and if someone proposes a circuit (you have rejected) (and others agree it should work) try and learn why it didn't originally work for you. Firstly though, what are you trying to achieve with the rectification and do you mean full-wave or half wave?

Comment: A lot of this depends on the details of whether it's supposed to be single supply etc. Andy's suggestion is perfectly reasonable. One key take-away from his answer is that you should block the DC offset from the electret _before_ rectifying.

Comment: @spehro I did say that in my answer for input and output.

Comment: @Andyaka He should accept your answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I don't think he listens too well dude LOL!!!

Comment: @user3396919 Assuming that your application does not require going more that 10kHz and you have at least 100mV available at input. then you can use CA358 without DC offset. Source resistance it is critical. CA3140 from Intersil used more frequently in such applications www. http://www.peduto.it/data_sheet/CA3140.pdf  page 17. It is still available in RS. A more precise solution is to use the OPA2237 from TI (SMD only) in “ideal diode” design http://www.peduto.it/data_sheet/CA3140.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is what [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier) says: -

[image]

This will work fine providing you AC couple your microphone to the input and AC couple the output. Simple series capacitance will do the decoupling of the DC signal.

PS it's only half wave rectification shown above.

[This](http://www.play-hookey.com/analog/feedback_circuits/full-wave_rectifier.html) is a full wave circuit

Comment: ok I tried this circuit:  [link](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_FdGFE8NBDgc/S_EmufCkuJI/AAAAAAAAC0Q/IuR1zenmsGs/spy-ear-circuit-diagram.gif) , the circuit's amplification is not high and with high noise yet it removes the DC offset.
[link](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/Microphone_Preamp_Electret.gif) has an excellent amplification yet it does not rectify or remove the DC offset.

Comment: sorry dude but these circuits work. They are standard circuits and if they didn't work for you then you did something wrong

Comment: any advices on how to optimize the second [circuit](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/Microphone_Preamp_Electret.gif), I mean how to fully rectify it and remove the DC offset? Excuse me but I'm new to this. thanks in advance :)

Comment: ac coupling the input and the output gets rid of unwelcome offsets.

Comment: sorry I'm only commenting on circuits in my answer dude.

Comment: I built the second [circuit](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/Microphone_Preamp_Electret.gif) again and I followed it by the full wave rectifier you suggested and I put a capacitor of 4.7uF in series with with the output, the input already has a a 100nF capacitor connected. The result was good but the noise seems to be more (it reaches now 1V), knowing that the output of this circuit will be read by an arduino (which can rear a maximum of 5V) so the 1V noise is high. Any suggestions?

Comment: The LM358 circuit is not a low noise amplifier and it wouldn't be my choice.

Comment: try putting a 100uF capacitor across R4. That will kill power supply noise to an extent.